# What is the Javascript `-->` operator?

Tags: javascript

I saw some code online and it had this in it:

```js
document.writeln("<p>");
for (var line = 10; line --> 0;) { // --> operator here
  for (var i = 10; i --> 0;) {     // --> operator here
    var s = (Math.floor((Math.random()*2)%2)) ? "╱" : "╲";
    document.write(s);
  }
  document.writeln("<br>");
}
document.writeln("</p>");
```

```css
p { 
  line-height: 18px; 
  font-size: 18px; 
}
```

What exactly is this `-->` operator and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a `-->` operator.

That is just a [Postfix Decrement Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3.2) immediately followed by a [Greater Than Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.2).

It would more usually be written as:

```
for (var i = 10; i-- > 0;) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a decrement (--) followed by a comparison (>). These would normally be written with a space to make it easier to read.